# Can I get the current screen name on asp.net without strict encoding (Hard coding)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Any way to get the current screen name of asp.net without hard coding?

```sh
string ScreenName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

I tried this and got the full url.

Comment: I wonder what this has to do with C? Also what is "screen name" in this context? In normal use I would expect "screen name" to imply the name the user uses (e.g. "Eranda Madusanka")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the domain name from the url, use the following code:

```
string[] hostParts = new System.Uri(sURL).Host.Split('.');
string domain = String.Join(".", hostParts.Skip(Math.Max(0, hostParts.Length - 2)).Take(2));
```

or :

```
var host = new System.Uri(sURL).Host;
var domain = host.Substring(host.LastIndexOf('.', host.LastIndexOf('.') - 1) + 1);
```

where "sURL" is your URL.

Comment: Um, how do we know that OP wants the host?

Comment: Finally I found. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I found a code. For me the `string path` is good

```sh
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    // http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx

    string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    // /TESTERS/Default6.aspx

    string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
    // localhost
```

Comment: I strongly suggest explaining what you want in questions in future. There's not much point in posting if we don't know what you need, as can be seen from the two wildly different answers you have received.